# Check if a child exists

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6, addchild

I have two Scenes. In scene 1, there is a script which automatically adds a child using `addChild(nameObject);`, there is also a button go to the next scene.

When I come back from scene 2 to scene 1, the code generates another object. How do I make an AS3 script that checks if the child does already exist on the stage?

Comment: `contains(nameObject)`?
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#contains()

Answer (score 2):

You're most probably looking for the [`contains()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#contains()) method of a [`DisplayObjectContainer`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html):

> Determines whether the specified display object is a child of the
>   `DisplayObjectContainer` instance or the instance itself. The search
>   includes the entire display list including this `DisplayObjectContainer`
>   instance. Grandchildren, great-grandchildren, and so on each return
>   `true`.

```
if ( !contains(nameObject) ) {
    // the object is not a child of the container
    addChild(nameObject); 
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but I'd suggest (since the potential parent is known), that it would be more efficient to just do `if(nameObject.parent != this)` as then you're not doing a recursive search through all children.

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis It doesnt work, the object keeps on adding to the stage